# adb is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, cmd, path, adb, android-sdk-tools

I've downloaded [SDK Platform Tools](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r29.0.4-windows.zip), extracted and placed the content in the folder `C:\Android\platform-tools`:

[image]

I've also added the path to the `adb.exe` file to the `Environmental Variables`

[image]

but I still get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path should have

```
C:\Android\platform-tools
```

instead of

```
C:\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe
```